# Do all Class B and Class C towers operate 24/7?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace

For Class B airports, I think the answer is realistically yes, due to traffic flows. How about Class C airports? Are there any legal requirements that it has to operate in 24/7, or is a convention?

Comment: I believe KXNA is an example.

Comment: No, many class C airports close, for example [KGRB is attended 0500-2200](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KGRB) and closed at other times, during which the airspace turns into class E or G (can't remember).

Comment: Here is another example - KMRY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no. It's easy to find examples of class C towers that aren't 24/7, by checking in the [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/). Two examples are [KXNA](http://airnav.com/airport/KXNA) (as [mentioned](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/do-all-class-b-and-class-c-towers-operate-24-7#comment68882_27812) in the comments) which operates 1130-0500Z and [KHSV](http://airnav.com/airport/KHSV), which operates 1200-0600Z. Note that the airspace changes when the tower is closed: KXNA becomes class G, and KHSV becomes class E.

As for class B, I would also assume that they're 24/7. I checked a few (KATL, KBOS, KSEA) in the Chart Supplement and they are indeed 24/7 but I don't feel like checking them all :-)

Comment: [KNKX](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KNKX) although not public use is class B and is not continuously manned.

Comment: @RonBeyer That's an interesting example. The Chart Supplement says it's E, not B, but the TAC certainly makes it look like B.

Comment: [Wikipedia lists it under class B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Class_B_airports_in_the_United_States), that's where I got it from.